# compile angularjs ionic app with Phonegap Build

Tags: angularjs, cordova, steroids, ionic-framework

is it ok to compile a AngularJS+ Ionic app using Phonegap Build or Steroids ?
Or should I use another platform ?

I would like your feedback!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, yes you can use PhoneGap Build to build your application. We are using it to build our AngularJS + Onsen UI app, but it should also suitable for Ionic. The question isn't really about which front-end techniques you use, whether it is about your other needs such as [platform support](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/introduction_supported_platforms.md.html#Supported%20Platforms) (PhoneGap Build supports "only" iOS, Android and Windows Phone 8) and [plugins](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins) needed (again, PhoneGap Build doesn't automatically support every plugin there exists, but ~400 they support should be enough in most of the cases). If there limitations are okay for you, go ahead and try it. It is easy to setup and has quick builds almost out-of-box for your Cordova application.

About Steroids, I can't say anything as haven't used it.

Comment: @Louis: if you think that this answer was sufficient answer for your question, please don't hesitate to accept it! :)

Answer (score 0):

yes you can use PhoneGap Build to build your application on android and window phone but ios you need key Provisioning profile  good luck